# Why Apache Kafka broker is not available?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am running a **Kafka application** in Docker v24.0.5 / Windows 11 and a message error "Broker may not be available" occurred.

This is my **Docker-compose file** :

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    hostname: zoo1
    container_name: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_PORT: 2181
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/data:/data
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/datalog:/datalog

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.0
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka1:19092
      
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zoo1

  gateway:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/lac-puc/context-net-kafka-core/gwlocal6:latest
    container_name: gw
    ports:
      - "5500:5500/udp"
    environment:
      gw.port: "5500"
      gw.consumer.topics: GroupAdvertisement,PrivateMessageTopic,GroupMessageTopic,UniCast,PingConfig
      gw.consumer.auto.offset.reset: "latest"
      gw.consumer.bootstrap.servers: "kafka1:19092"
      gw.consumer.group.id: "gw-gateway"
      gw.producer.bootstrap.servers: "kafka1:19092"
      gw.producer.retries: "3"
      gw.producer.enable.idempotence: "true"
      gw.producer.linger.ms: "1"
      gw.producer.acks: "all"
      gw.poolsize: 1000
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
```

And the **error** **message** is the following:

```
[Thread-2] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 2.0.0
[Thread-2] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : 3402a8361b734732
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[Thread-3] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=gw-gateway] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I have tried to:

1. disable Firewall
2. change IP address from 127.0.0.1 to the IP of my machine
3. I have already visited most of the kafka unavailable discussions and they did not answer my query.

Any help?

Comment: `SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS` is not a valid variable for the broker, but you're going to need to show how/where `gw.consumer.bootstrap.servers` and `gw.producer.bootstrap.servers` actually get used in your other image or the output of the ProducerConfig and ConsumerConfig added to the logs, since env-vars typically don't have periods, and the Kafka broker does not start immediately, so your code will need to wait and connect and/or retry ... There's no firewall between two containers, and you shouldn't use/change to use IP addresses